# have upstart job prevent different job from stopping

Tags: upstart

I'm trying to find a way to have one upstart job, which is triggered when another job is stopping, from preventing that other job from really stopping.

Basically I have a service which runs, lets pretend apache, and I want to create another upstart job which will prevent that service from shutting down unless certain conditions are met. So I've created a "task" job to perform a few checks, and then if those checks don't pass, apache should not be allowed to shut down.

I thought I could do something such as the following:

```
start on stopping apache

task
script
if some_condition; then
    start --no-wait apache
fi
end script
```

But the other service still shuts down, it just gets immediately started back up. I can't have this, it must not shut down at all.

I've put a `sleep` statement in the above script, and it does delay the service from stopping. So if the service is still running, I would think I should be able to prevent it from shutting down.

Comment: Upstart won't abort starting or stopping a service. If the conditions are met, the action will happen. If the criteria to start or stop a service is wrong, it should be fixed in that service's .conf file. If some other service is erroneously trying to kill it, trap the signal or file a bug report to fix it's behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging through the upstart source code, the only time an upstart script can abort an operation is in the 'pre' phase (pre-start/pre-stop). When you use a trigger such as `start on stopping foo`, the service receives the event after the `pre-stop` phase for 'foo', so you cannot start it back up without it first stopping.

However when you have a `start on stopping foo` condition, you the 'foo' service wont stop until the service listening to the event finishes. So what I ended up doing is simply looping forever until the condition I'm checking is met. It's not the greatest solution but it works.

---

An alternate solution would also have been to create a `.override` file for the service and put a `pre-stop` script in the override. The condition could then be checked in the `pre-stop` and issuing a `start` will keep the service from stopping.

Unfortunately this doesn't quite work for me due to other complicated reasons, but it might be an option for anyone else trying to do this.

Comment: pre-stop scripts are not run if the job has no process. It should work fine for apache.

Comment: The `pre-stop` script not running isn't the issue. The issue is that you can't abort the stop from within the pre-stop script.

Comment: Really? `start; exit 0` always works to prevent upstart from killing the process for me. What is the specific issue?

Comment: @CameronNemo That doesn't prevent it from stopping, that just makes it start back up immediately after it stops.

Comment: What version of Upstart? I just tested it with version 1.11 and the pid was kept the same.

Comment: @CameronNemo Wait, sorry, you're right, `start` in a `pre-stop` does prevent it from stopping. It's been a while since I was working on this, and my recollection was bad (and I didn't read my own answer as it says it right there...). The issue is that if another service has a `start on stopping foo`, it gets triggered after the `pre-stop` phase of `foo` (it's in the `stopping` phase at that point), and once it gets to `stopping`, it must stop, there is no aborting it.